# PL/SQL exception in loop

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, exception

I have these 3 tables in the data base:
- Person
- Thing
- Category

The "category" table is new, so I have to write a script to migrate the data. Earlier a Person could have many things... now a person can have many categories and each category can have many things.

So I have to write a script that iterates through things and checks if a group has already been created for the thing and the person and if it hasn't, then create it and update the thing data. If the category was already created, just update the thing data.

```
declare
    -- thing
    v_thing_id thing.id%TYPE;
    v_thing_person_id thing.person_id%TYPE;
    v_thing_category_name thing.category_name%TYPE;
    v_thing_category_id thing.category_id%TYPE;

    -- category_name
    v_category_id category.id%TYPE;

    cursor c_thing_ids is
        select b.id
        from thing b
        where category_id is null
    ;

begin
    open c_thing_ids;

    loop
        -- iterate all the thing ids
        fetch c_thing_ids into v_thing_id;

        exit when c_thing_ids%NOTFOUND;

        -- look for already created category for current thing
        select e.id
        into v_category_name_id
        from category e
        where e.person_id = v_thing_person_id
        and e.category_name = v_thing_category_name;

        -- if exists: update thing
        if v_category_name_id is not null then
            update thing
                set category_id = v_category_name_id
                where id = v_thing_id;
        else
        -- if not: create category and update thing
            insert into category (id, category_name)
                values (HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,  v_thing_category_name);
            select e.id
                into v_category_name_id
                from category e
                where e.person_id = v_thing_person_id
                and e.category_name = v_thing_category_name;
            update thing
                set category_id = v_category_name_id
                where id = v_thing_id;
        end if; 
    end loop;
end;
```

I am not an expert with PL/SQL, in fact this is the second thing I do with it "in real life", so, as expected I get an error: ORA-01403 in line:

```
select e.id
    into v_category_name_id
    from category e
    where e.person_id = v_thing_person_id
    and e.category_name = v_thing_category_name;
```

How should I handle this? I tried with exception when no_data_found but then it complains about the exception not being in the right place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve problem:

```
-- look for already created category for current thing
begin 
  select e.id
      into v_category_name_id
      from category e
      where e.person_id = v_thing_person_id
      and e.category_name = v_thing_category_name;
exception when no_data_found then
  v_category_name_id := null;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, I forgot to use begin/end inside the loop. Using it I can declare an exception block.